# Bootstrap-sass change navbar color

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, view, bootstrap-sass

I am attempting to apply the navbar-inverse class to my left navbar. This is my code which lives inside my layout file:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-left">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
      <ul>
      item one
      </ul>
      <ul>
      item two
      </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

However, my navbar still shows up in default colors. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Can you provide an example with jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap doesn't style the `.navbar-inverse` element directly, it styles the `.navbar-inverse .navbar-inner` element instead.  So you would need to do something like:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-left">
  <div class="navbar navbar-inner">
    <ul>
      item one
    </ul>
    <ul>
      item two
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```